# WooCommerce category page is blank

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm usgin WP 4.3.1 and WooCommerce 2.4.6.
After installed almost everything works fine. I go to /shop page and products list there.
I clicked to /product-category/digital-product which is Digital product category but it is blank page. Empty page with just sidebar!

What i have to do to make it show products or sub categories?

Here are permalink settings.
Common Settings
http://localhost/wp**/%postname%/** where /wp is my WordPress root.
Product category base: **product-category**
Product tag base: **product-tag**
Product permalink base
http://localhost/wp**/shop/%product_cat%**

Comment: In your active theme create `woocommerce/category-digital-product.php` and style it the way you like.

Comment: 1st method: Disable all plugins ( except WooCommerce ) and check if your issue solved .

2nd method: try to switch your theme and check to see if this solved your problem.

Comment: @TarunMahashwari If I use Storefront theme which is by WooThemes. It showing sub categories with (number of products) but not showing products. And I clicked into those sub categories it said no products.
Deactivated all other plugins seems to works. It conflicts with Polylang!

Thank you.

Comment: Dear @vee if your issue is fixed, please accept this solution as an answer. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1st method:**

Disable all plugins ( except WooCommerce ) and check if your issue solved. 
If this fix your issue, then try to activate your plugins one by one and locate the plugin which is responsible for this issue.

**2nd method:**

Try to switch your theme and check to see if this solved your problem.
If this fix your issue, then inform about this issue to your theme developer and ask them to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

find, if there is a file inside your theme root path named woocommerce.php, if you found it, just delete it or rename it to woocommerce.del.php then retry,
This thing fixed my blank page issue.